# Отличие API level < 11 от API level > 11

Tags: java, android

Какие есть важные отличия API level < 11 и API level > 11

Answer (score 2):

API Level это просто целое число, которое однозначно идентифицирует ревизию рабочего окружения программных библиотек (framework API revision), которая предоставляется версией платформы (операционной системой) Android.

Таким образом главное отличие - это версия Android, с которой придется столкнуться.

Отличия API 11-ой версии от более старой или более новой версии сложно описать в двух словах. В этом случае стоит прочитать официальные ресурсы:

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.0.html

Так же ситуацию может прояснить задача для которой вы подбираете API level.

Comment: я имел ввиду в чем отличие этих версий?)

Comment: @Martinez Toni обновил

Comment: Вы работаете android разработчиком?

Comment: @Martinez Toni разбираюсь на досуге